# Improving pandas performance with apply method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm working on pandas for high performance calculations, the below function gives **1 loop, best of 5: 7.24 s per loop** for 50,000 rows.

I have to scale it to 1 million rows.

How to vectorise the function and apply to all rows. So that overall performance can be improved?

```
def weightedFlowAmt(startDate,endDate,tradeDate,tradeAmt):
  startInDays = datetime.strptime(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
  endInDays = datetime.strptime(endDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
  tradeInDays = datetime.strptime(tradeDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
  differenceTradeAndEnd=abs((endInDays - tradeInDays).days)
  differenceStartAndEnd=abs((endInDays - startInDays).days)
  weighted_FlowAmt = (tradeAmt * differenceTradeAndEnd)/differenceStartAndEnd

mutatedCashFlow['flow'] = mutatedCashFlow.apply(lambda row:
        weightedFlowAmt(row['startDate'], row['EndDate'], row['tradeDate'],
                        row['tradeAmount']),
    axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can remove `apply` and use vectorized functions:

```
mutatedCashFlow['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(mutatedCashFlow['startDate'])
mutatedCashFlow['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(mutatedCashFlow['EndDate'])
mutatedCashFlow['tradeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(mutatedCashFlow['tradeDate'])

diffTradeAndEnd=((mutatedCashFlow['EndDate']-mutatedCashFlow['tradeDate']).dt.days).abs()
diffStartAndEnd=((mutatedCashFlow['EndDate']-mutatedCashFlow['startDate']).dt.days).abs()

mutatedCashFlow['flow'] = (mutatedCashFlow['tradeAmount']*diffTradeAndEnd)/diffStartAndEnd
```

Alternative:

```
mutatedCashFlow['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(mutatedCashFlow['startDate'])
mutatedCashFlow['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(mutatedCashFlow['EndDate'])
mutatedCashFlow['tradeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(mutatedCashFlow['tradeDate'])

diffTradeAndEnd=mutatedCashFlow['EndDate'].sub(mutatedCashFlow['tradeDate']).dt.days.abs()
diffStartAndEnd=mutatedCashFlow['EndDate'].sub(mutatedCashFlow['startDate']).dt.days.abs()

mutatedCashFlow['flow'] = mutatedCashFlow['tradeAmount'].mul(diffTradeAndEnd)
                                                        .div(diffStartAndEnd)
print (mutatedCashFlow)
```

Comment: This is exactly right.  OP can hopefully do it herself next time, simply by taking it one step at a time.  When the very first step is to call `strptime()` on every cell in the table, that's an easy win for a vectorized function like `to_datetime`.  The whole thing is almost a trivial conversion apart from needing to know the name `to_datetime` and then the magic `.dt` accessor before you can do `.days`.

Comment: Give me as sec, but what is `tradeAmt` ?

Comment: @jezrael it's being passed from  DataFrame (lambda row:
        weightedFlowAmt(row['startDate'], row['EndDate'], row['tradeDate'],
                        row['tradeAmount']),

Comment: @jezrael You're a MVP man, f*****g hell this is the message now **1 loop, best of 5: 930 µs per loop**

Comment: wau, it is really faaast. Thank you.